# Baking regular lights in eevee?

Tags: baking, lighting

I just finished lighting a scene and was wondering if there was any options to bake the lighting? Not the indirect lighting but actual stuff like lamps,sun,point and spotlight lights I can't seem to find any button other then indirect or cubemap baking I'm using blender release canditate 2

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you meant for bake lighting was like a common bake procedure which being used in game. As far as I know, currently there is no option to bake lighting to textures in Eevee, the options just exists in Cycles.

Comment: Yeah similar to how games bake lighting that way is what i'm trying to do in eevee

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way in eevee for now unless you are using Cycles

Comment: Also may be off-topic on the question I was asking but I also had another issue relating to lighting. I'm trying to use fog by using a volume scatter on a cube but whenever I try using it 2 or 3 of my point lights just start glowing like this:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/389629018049216513/602402692450484234/f643545e0d040b1f4019caa5a9798242.png

Comment: perhaps you activate Bloom in your scene that's why it become glowing like that

Comment: even when the bloom is turned off it still happens

Comment: I think it is just the way the lighting react in a volume then,,, but you can try to increase Light Clamping in your Volume Lighting setting to reduce the glow

Comment: Thank you that seemed to have fixed it!

Comment: Great ! Happy Blending !